# Hive SQL Query with a Nested Subquery as A Condition in CASE WHEN Judgment

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

AS the title, my query is like:

```
SELECT
COUNT(
    DISTINCT (CASE WHEN id IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT id
        FROM some_table
        WHERE year = 2019
        AND month IN (1, 2, 3)
    ) tmp AND (*OTHERS CONDITIONS*) THEN id END)
) AS devices
FROM some_table
WHERE year = 2019
AND month IN (1, 2, 3);
```

However, I kept receiving this error:

```
cannot recognize input near 'SELECT' 'DISTINCT' 'id' in expression specification
```

How can I workaround?

Comment: Doesn't the second half of the query already guaranteed that those conditions are met? If so then only the "other conditions" are relevant to filter on. It's very possible you can't use a subquery there but I suggest the `tmp` alias is going to cause errors and the `distinct` is pretty much redundant.

Answer (score 1):

you can not use subquery like this. Change the subquery to join and use it in case when.

```
SELECT
COUNT(
    DISTINCT (CASE WHEN tmpid is not null 
         AND (*OTHERS CONDITIONS*) THEN id END)
) AS devices
FROM some_table
left join (SELECT DISTINCT id as tmpid
        FROM some_table
        WHERE year = 2019
        AND month IN (1, 2, 3)
    ) tmp on tmp.tmpid = id
WHERE year = 2019
AND month IN (1, 2, 3);
```